# xades4j signature in node

Tags: signature, xades4j

Hello I need sign between nodes

```
</ext:ExtensionContent>
</ext:UBLExtension>
<ext:UBLExtension>
    <ext:ExtensionContent>
        <!-- here signature -->
    </ext:ExtensionContent>
</ext:UBLExtension>
</ext:UBLExtensions>

new Enveloped(signer).sign(elem);
```

I am using xades-epes enveloped with policy and claimedrole. Please I need help.

Answer (score 1):

The `Enveloped` class is meant for straightforward scenarios. To have more control, use the methods on [`XadesSigner`](http://luisgoncalves.github.io/xades4j/javadocs/1.4.0/reference/xades4j/production/XadesSigner.html#sign(xades4j.production.SignedDataObjects, org.w3c.dom.Node)) directly.

You'll need to [add the enveloped transform](https://github.com/luisgoncalves/xades4j/wiki/DefiningSignedResources#transforms) manually to the data object being signed.